# Convert python dictionary into panda dataframe and save as csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I am trying to save python object as dataframe and convert to cvs.

```
import stereo as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = st.io.read_gem(data_path_ECig_M)
data2 = st.io.read_gem(data_path_Ctrl_M )

# Preprocessing and filter cells and genes
data1.tl.cal_qc()

data2.tl.cal_qc()

data1.tl.filter_cells(min_gene=50, pct_counts_mt=10, inplace=True)

data2.tl.filter_cells(min_gene=50, pct_counts_mt=10, inplace=True)

# Merging
data = st.utils.data_helper.merge(data1, data2)

# Normalize and perform umap
data.tl.raw_checkpoint()

data.tl.normalize_total()

data.tl.log1p()

data.tl.pca(use_highly_genes=False, n_pcs=30, res_key='pca', svd_solver='arpack' )

data.tl.batches_integrate(pca_res_key='pca', res_key='pca_integrated')


data.tl.neighbors(pca_res_key='pca_integrated', n_pcs=30, res_key='neighbors_integrated', n_jobs= 8 )

data.tl.umap(pca_res_key='pca_integrated', neighbors_res_key='neighbors_integrated', res_key='umap_integrated')
data.plt.batches_umap(res_key='umap_integrated')

data.tl.leiden(neighbors_res_key='neighbors_integrated', res_key='leiden', resolution=0.4)

data.plt.cluster_scatter(res_key='leiden')


# Split the above merged data
splitData=st.utils.data_helper.split(data)
```

The merged data object has following key

```
>> **data**
StereoExpData object with n_cells X n_genes = 32117 X 14782
```

```
>>> data.

data.array2sparse(             data.cell_borders            
data.check(                   data.format_check(           
data.genes_pairwise           data.offset_y                
data.position                 data.sparse2array(           
data.to_df(                    data.attr                    
data.cell_names               data.exp_matrix              
data.format_range             data.get_sn_from_path(       
data.output                   data.position_offset         
data.sub_by_index(             data.bin_size                
data.cells                     data.file                    
data.gene_names               data.issparse(                
data.output_check(            data.raw                     
data.sub_by_name(              data.bin_type                
data.cells_matrix             data.file_check(              data.genes
data.merged                   data.partitions               data.shape
data.sub_exp_matrix_by_name(   data.bin_type_check(         
data.cells_pairwise           data.file_format             
data.genes_matrix             data.offset_x                  data.plt 
data.sn                        data.tl



# Merged data is converted to dataframe using data.to_df()

df= data.to_df()
 
df.to_csv('Outputdf_data_results.csv', index=False)
```

Can you suggest how to convert data.tl.result to data frame and csv

```
>>> **data.tl.result**

{'gene_exp_leiden': group              1      2      3      4      5      6      7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14   15    16    17    18   19

0610030E20Rik    349    316    259    170    179    160    135   123   107    91    65    82    53    50    5    40    44    15    5

0610040J01Rik    649    573    819    269    391    357    618   411   212   154   324   200    77   125   17    46    80    29    6

1110038F14Rik   2860   2509   1436   1538   1638   1263   1022   803   830   594   624   590   552   289   27   281   277   136   62

1110065P20Rik  36791  26030  13308  21633  19663  14894  11962  5506  7391  7410  6231  6399  6119  1396  306  3159  1970  1490  465

1500009L16Rik  14425   6713   2485   2951   5876   4358   3153  1856  2249  1179  1252  1429  1068   233   94  1808   193   475   61

...              ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...  ...

Zzz3            1583   1632   1041    951   1035    789    698   546   535   425   321   361   285   206   16   172   175    72   45

mrpl11          6741   5861   3458   4312   3651   2935   2669  1563  2130  1407  1105  1491  1203   516   54   894   580   250  139

mrpl24          4890   4337   2004   3217   2600   2337   1475   913  1074  1402   756   992   874   211   44   438   315   217   60

mrpl9           6123   5592   3067   3435   3438   2945   1969  1473  1814  1572  1101  1168  1149   502   72   471   560   263   94

rnf141          4478   2675   1799   2411   2893   1579   1616   806  1108   698   866  1163   674   233   41   398   271   160   48

[14782 rows x 19 columns]}
```

I want to convert data.tl.result to dataframe and save as csv

I tried the following, which was also suggested in one of the post, but did not work

```
pd.DataFrame(data=data.tl.result)
```

Comment: `data.tl.result` does not seem to be a Dictionary.  Please explain type and format.